# react-redux state works in redux devTools but can't render it to the page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to make a get request to my backend with react-redux, when I look at the redux dev tools I see that the state is updated and the products are put inside the state(which is good), but when I try to map the products or `console.log(products)` it gives me undefined, I'm following a tutorial and I'm doing exactly as the instructor, here's my code what I'm I doing wrong?

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listProducts } from "../../actions/productActions";

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products } = productList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <div className="card-div mt-5">{products.map((product) => {
        <h1>{product.name}</h1>;
      })}</div>; //TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
};
```

here's my dev tools to ensure you that the state is updating and data is correctly fetched:

[actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkXsf.png)

[products list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJQ0D.png)

Comment: const { loading, error, products } = productList; you are assigning an array to an object and then you require that array from the element of an object. which is impossible to map. You should assign an array of productList to array of products and then map that products. Hope it will help.

Comment: @Shoaib the ```products``` in ```const { loading, error, products } = productList;``` is an array inside an object, I don't see anything wrong with that. what changes would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Check for existence of productList before attempting to map them.

Try this:

```
const Home = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
    const { loading, error, products } = productList;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listProducts());
    }, [dispatch, listProducts]);

    return <div className="card-div mt-5">{!! products && products.map((product) => {
        <h1>{product.name}</h1>;
    })}</div>; //TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
};
```

try adding listProducts to the array of parameters for your useEffect call.

Comment: tried it: I don't get the error but the list Items are not rendered

Comment: I think the array is productList, not products??

Comment: I have updated the (product list) image in the question, see that the productList is an object and inside that object there is products which is an array!

Comment: then the path to the products array should be productList.products

Comment: which has no difference with ```products``` in ```const { loading, error, products } = productList;```

Comment: good point, what about adding listProducts to the parameter array for useEffect?

Comment: did you find solution? I have exactly same issue. Funny thing, I made new component for different route in my api (backend log are OK), and it works...